# how to always prepend schema name in jpql - jpa

Tags: jpa, schema, database-schema, jpql

I have tables across 3 different database schemas. JPA confuses itself because it tries to find the table at the wrong schema.

I know I can specify the schema at the @Table annotation but, one of the schemas varies and I can't block it's name.

So, my idea is to tell JPA to always prepend the schema name in the queries it creates, whether I define it or not in the @Table annotation.
Is this possible?
Any other solution?

Thanks!

Note: I'm not using Hibernate, I'm using Toplink.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JPA *orm.xml* and define the schema/catalog in there in the global section. Works fine with DataNucleus JPA when you do that.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, although to create a orm.xml is a "deviation from standard" in our development policy.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your DBA to see if he can create a schema that will merge all three schemas.  That way your application will only have to deal with one schema.  DB2 for zOS can do this and it saved having to create different orm.xml files for each environment.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. Each application has it's own database and a small part is centralized in one common database. That's why there's a part of the schema name that always changes and other that doesn't.

Comment: That's too bad.  I know for our DB2 installation we can set it up so that we can have a common schema for each app which maps to the real schema. e.g. APP1.CODES, APP2.CODES maps to REFERENCE.CODES, APP1.COREDATA maps to PROVIDERS.COREDATA.  It isn't a common feature or knowledge which is why it is best to ask the DBA because we didn't know it was even possible until we asked them.

Comment: I just remembered the word he used "SYNONYMS".  Hope that helps. Good luck!